# how to call a another exe in in window service

Tags: visual-c++

i made the program and create its exe file i want to add my exe file in to window service ,
because when the computer start my program will be automatically start just because of window service so please can any one tell me how to add my exe in to window service

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly - You have a windows service, and you now want to call an exe from this windows service.

The easiest way is to use:

```
Process.Start("example.exe");
```

Visual C++:

```
Process::Start(S"IExplore.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

JL answered the one interpretation. If on the other hand you want to CREATE a Windows Service from an EXE, then there are many ways to do so.

[How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx) windows API,  or [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) C++ function